# print object data in table Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i wanna display some values of an object, 
the object  has the next structure:

```
{
 0:
   {    id: "value",
        topic: "value",
        description: "value",
        ...
   }
 1:
   {
    ...
   }
}
```

and this is my code for display in a table with `id=cursos`
it has an ajax call before so I do this inside `.done()` method
the thing is that when I use double each to call teh first object and display its attributes it doesn't show anything, but when I call them by its name, without `$.each()` it is showed in table format,
**How can I show the values of my objects in  table format using $.each(), just to save code lines** note: i have also changed the `.html()` for `.append()` and it's the same result.

```
    resultado.done(
function (data){//success
$("#cursos").append($("<tr>").append(
$("<td>").append("Tema"),
$("<td>").append("Indice"),
$("<td>").append("Descripción"),
$("<td>").append("Fecha"),
$("<td>").append("Idioma"),
$("<td>").append("Imagen"),
$("<td>").append("Enlaces"),
$("<td>").append("Nivel"),
$("<td>").append("Palabras clave"),
$("<td>").append("Autor"),
$("<td>").append("Escuela"),
$("<td>").append("Categoria"),
$("<td>").append("Subcategoria")
),
$("<tr>").html(
$.each(data, function (key, data1) {
    $.each(data1, function (index, datos) {
       console.log("index", datos);
       $("<td>").append(datos);
    })
})
/* if this block comment is removed it works
$("<td>").append(data[0].tema),
$("<td>").append(data[0].indice),
$("<td>").append(data[0].descripcion),
$("<td>").append(data[0].fecha),
$("<td>").append(data[0].idioma),
$("<td>").append(data[0].imagen),
$("<td>").append(data[0].enlaces),
$("<td>").append(data[0].nivel),
$("<td>").append(data[0].keywords),
$("<td>").append(data[0].autorId),
$("<td>").append(data[0].escuelasId),
$("<td>").append(data[0].categoriaId),
$("<td>").append(data[0].subcategoriaId)*/
)
);

//data[0].tema

}//function DONE
);//done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var dataCollection = {
0: {
    id: "id0",
    topic: "topic0",
    description: "desc0"
},
1: {
    id: "id1",
    topic: "topic1",
    description: "desc1"
},
2: {
    id: "id2",
    topic: "topic2",
    description: "desc2"
}
};

$.each(dataCollection, function(index) {
  $("table#cursos").append("<tr>");
  $.each(dataCollection[index], function(key, value) {
      $("table#cursos").append("<td>" + value + "</td>");
  });
  $("table#cursos").append("</tr>");
});
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4k8x0pc/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: That works... but i wish i could use $("<td>")  instead of append, thx for your help that is also shorten than the way i can display the object

Comment: Firstly, if you want to refer to td elements with jquery, use $("td") - I'm not sure that would help you here as it would select every td element on the page.  You might be able to use something like $(#cursos td:last-child") to select the last td element in the cursos table.  See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for more info

Comment: The append statements all add to the Table directly, but a tbody is added and the td fields are outside of the tr rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <!--http://stackoverflow.com/a/8563020/3200163-->
    <!--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562744/how-to-loop-through-this-nested-object-json-array-and-build-an-html-string-with-->
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    var data = {
        "sEcho": 1,
        "total": "1710",
        "aaData": [
            [
                "Help",
                "http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2011\/09\/dt_intfc4e732d1f1276d_4e76fab1e95bd.mp3?King_of_Spain_Entropy_02_Animals_Part_1.mp3",
                "1784",
                "3",
                0,
                null,
                "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
            ],
            [
                "A Day In The Life",
                "http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2011\/09\/dt_intfc4e732d1f1276d_4e76f5fc253a1.mp3?JenWood_Zeppelin.mp3",
                "3573",
                "3",
                0,
                null,
                "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
            ]
        ]
    }
    var str = "";
    for (var item in data.aaData) {
        str += '<tr>';
        for (idata in data.aaData[item]) {
            str += '<td>' + data.aaData[item][idata] + '</td>';
        }
        str += '</tr>';
    }


    $('body').append("<table>" + str + "</table>");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code creates a table correctly :)